# Jabber SDK requirements, costs and possibilities?

Tags: xmpp, telephony, cucm

Im posting this jabber sdk question to stackoverflow because the specific forums on cisco do no generate any response and the technical support of cisco first wants a contract before answering any (basic) questions. Perhaps anyone here has some insights into them. The contents of my post on the cisco forum( https://communities.cisco.com/thread/66173):

Im an it developer looking to create a web based solution for our customer to make calls to their customers using jabber (to be specific a loan officer in a bank environment could call their customer to discuss their outstanding loan application). After reading the getting started guide for jabber sdk and trying out the sample i still have a lot of questions that remain unanswered. If anybode could clarify these points this would be a great help:

1. Making calls using jabber sdk in web applications is obviously possible. However it is not quite clear if these calls can be made to all supplied telephone numbers or just to numbers/(ldap)directories registered on the (cucm server). Our requirement as described is to make employee to customer calls and not internal calls (the reverse is if i'm not mistaken suited to jabber guest)
2. After an obscure sample tutorial which ended up not working () i finally manged to get it up and running by using a shared/reserved lab on the sandbox dev net environment using anyconnect to setup a vpn to sandbox. Which leads me to the question of what server requirments are needed? Should our customer buy/set up a cucm server or are there hosted solutions to make use of? Is the sanbox devnet purely for development and testing or can it also be used for production?
3. When using a softphone is there any specific software required on the device (e.g. the end users PC) to make calls other than an active internet connection?
4. What are the costs (indication) of using the jabber SDK? As far is i could make out it depends mainly on the backend server setup (cisco contract/ cucm software license etc) but i would like to get a clear idea of what to expect
5. Is call metadata being registerd somehow in the cucm server or do you have to store them yourself (e.g. can i retrieve this information via the unique callid at a later moment or do i have to register such inf(call duration, line info etc) myself using the scrippt callback handlers

Perhaps some questions are obvious but were just starting to explore the jabber SDK and the information/help documents are not all that clear at times.

Thanks in advance